# Edit button not found on gerrit

Tags: gerrit

My gerrit version is 2.10, java is 1.8. When I open my commit, the files are shown but there is no "Edit" button. Then click the committed files, there still none 'Edit' button. Should I make some special configuration?

Comment: Your question needs some clarifications to get a decent answer

Answer (score 2):

[Inline Editing](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-inline-edit.html) was added as a new feature in Gerrit 2.11, see its [Release Notes](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.11.html#_web_ui). The version 2.10 that you're running is very outdated.